# Need help to determine nth-child value

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I set items `1, 2, 3` to `width: 33.33%` and `4, 5` to `width: 50%` and so on using `nth-child` selector ?

Like this :

```
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
<!-- and so on -->
```

Comment: using javascript and/or css classes would make it more easier, don't you think?

Comment: héhé sure, but I wanna improve my css skill ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is!
Watchout if the parent of your divs contains other tags, it can totally mess up the way elements are counted!

```css
.container * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
}

.container :nth-child(5n+1), .container :nth-child(5n+2), .container :nth-child(5n+3) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.container :nth-child(5n+4), .container :nth-child(5n) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
  <div></div> <!-- width 50% -->
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank a lot you helped me to improve my way of thinking about CSS

Answer (score 1):

Set difrennt classes to `width 33.33%` and `width 50%`  and style in css

```css
.minWidth{
width:33.33%;
background-color:red;
}
.maxWidth{
width:50%;
background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="minWidth">1</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="minWidth">2</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="minWidth">3</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="maxWidth">4</div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div class="maxWidth">5</div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div class="minWidth">6</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="minWidth">7</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="minWidth">8</div> <!-- width 33.33% -->
<div class="maxWidth"></div> <!-- width 50% -->
<div></div>
```

Comment: héhé sure, but I wanna improve my css skill ;)